# cardano-node goes down after "cardano-cli query pool-params"

Tags: cardano-cli, cardano-node

Making this query to my cardano-cli

```
cardano-cli query pool-params \
    --stake-pool-id pool13crd2ljx87988umk22er6ynwadfwdqupdpcq6prc6v59z62kxse \
    --mainnet
```

Makes my cardano-node goes down. Is this normal behaviour?
I guess not. How can I check why is this happening?

This is the log:

```
Jun 18 08:38:21 ip-172-31-10-236 cardano-node[1948]: [ip-172-3:cardano.node.ChainDB:Notice:540] [2021-06-18 08:38:21.15 UTC] Chain extended, new tip: 47e663c6efcfd52f6895e020032bfb672deddb8a3d1047a1c40d4ef186177ff0 at slot 32439210
Jun 18 08:39:21 ip-172-31-10-236 cardano-node[1948]: [ip-172-3:cardano.node.BlockFetchDecision:Info:550] [2021-06-18 08:39:21.53 UTC] [TraceLabelPeer (ConnectionId {localAddress = 172.31.10.236:34107, remoteAddress = 52.15.190.154:6000}) (Right [At (Block {blockPointSlot = SlotNo 32439270, blockPointHash = 449361583216f3fe0ec748bc32ea22f3ef3a9fe3e951845e017e49698b65a6fb})])]
Jun 18 08:39:21 ip-172-31-10-236 cardano-node[1948]: [ip-172-3:cardano.node.ChainDB:Notice:540] [2021-06-18 08:39:21.54 UTC] Chain extended, new tip: 449361583216f3fe0ec748bc32ea22f3ef3a9fe3e951845e017e49698b65a6fb at slot 32439270
Jun 18 08:39:49 ip-172-31-10-236 cardano-node[1947]: /home/ubuntu/cardano-my-node/startBlockProducingNode.sh: line 9:  1948 Killed                  /usr/local/bin/cardano-node run --topology ${TOPOLOGY} --database-path ${DB_PATH} --socket-path ${SOCKET_PATH} --host-addr ${HOSTADDR} --port ${PORT} --config ${CONFIG}
Jun 18 08:39:49 ip-172-31-10-236 systemd[1]: cardano-node.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=137/n/a
Jun 18 08:39:49 ip-172-31-10-236 systemd[1]: cardano-node.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jun 18 08:39:54 ip-172-31-10-236 systemd[1]: cardano-node.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 1.
Jun 18 08:39:54 ip-172-31-10-236 systemd[1]: Stopped Cardano node service.
Jun 18 08:39:54 ip-172-31-10-236 systemd[1]: Started Cardano node service.
Jun 18 08:39:56 ip-172-31-10-236 cardano-node[64305]: Listening on http://127.0.0.1:12798
Jun 18 08:39:57 ip-172-31-10-236 cardano-node[64305]: [ip-172-3:cardano.node.networkMagic:Notice:5] [2021-06-18 08:39:56.52 UTC] NetworkMagic 764824073
```

I don't have any problem with queries like:

```
cardano-cli query utxo --address ...
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what "goes down" means? Can you share the cardano node log?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a high likelyhood that you run out of memory when running that query, as it involves querying subset of ledger, which can cause a spike to your memory usage (if it is marginal to minimum recommendations). Assuming you're on Linux , you can check via `dmesg -T | grep cardano` to see if it was caused by OOM event.

If not, you'd need to check logs and provide more details

Comment: Yes, that was the reason. Thank you. Here the log: `[Fri Jun 18 08:39:48 2021] Out of memory: Killed process 1948 (cardano-node) total-vm:1074772472kB, anon-rss:5803728kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB, UID:1000 pgtables:11620kB oom_score_adj:0`